# How to get all possible combinations of this list?

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics, permutation

I'm trying to get all possible combinations of `{0,-1}` for a certain length. So let's say I want length 2. Then I want my output to be

```
{0,0}, {0,-1}, {-1,0}, {-1,-1}
```

and if I want lengths 3 then I want my output to be

```
{0,0,0}, {0,0,-1}, {0,-1,0}, {0,-1,-1}, {-1,0,0}, {-1,0,-1}, {-1,-1,-1}, {-1,-1,0}
```

The Permutations function isn't working for this how I'd like it to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Tuples`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html):

```
Tuples[{0, -1}, n]
```

This gives all lists of length n formed from the elements in the set 
`{0, -1}`.

Comment: Thank you! Not sure how I didn't know about this